# class-table-mapper design php and ZF

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, models, mappers

is there a better way to work with ZF useing the mappers, real life objects and table_objects.

This is how I do it with Zend Framework:

```
class User_DbTable extends Zend_DB_Table_Abstract{
      protected $_name = "user"; // name of the table
}
```

the user class -> user object:

```
class User{
  protected $_id;
  protected $_name;
  protected $_addresses; //list of OBJs

  public function set_name($_name){
    $this->_name = $_name;
  }
  public function get_name(){
    return $this->_name;
  }
  public function set_adresses($_addresses){
    $this->_addresses = $_addresses;
  }
// and so on....
}
```

the mapper:

```
class UserMapper{
   protected $userTBL;

   public function __construct(){
     $this->userTBL = new User_DbTable();
   }
   public function __fatchAll(){
     $select = $this->userTBL->select();
     foreach($this->userTBL->fetchAll($select) as $row){
       $user = new User(); // model
       $user->set_name($row->name);
       // gat all the addreses of this user with eg. AddressMapper()
       $user->set_addresses($addresses); // array of object of address just like User
       $users[] = $user;
     }
     return $users;
   }
}
```

usage in controller:
list action:

```
$userMP = new UserMapper();
$this->view->users = $userMP->__fatchAll();
```

or add/save action:

```
$newUser = new User();
$newUser->set_name('somename');
$userMP = new UserMapper();
$userMP->save($newUser);
```

Comment: You can use whatever coding standard you like - but the underscores in the middle of the method names stand out like a sore thumb to me. If you're going to be writing a lot with ZF, I would stickToCamelCase because all of the libraries, documentation, samples etc follow this.

Comment: view few presentetions http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney  especially http://www.slideshare.net/weierophinney/architecting-your-models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZF lets you extend the `Zend_Db_Table_Row` class, and tell your Zend_Db_Table class to always use it. This way, you can access all of the `Zend_Db_Table_Row` features, while adding your own logic on top.

You can do that like this

```
class User_DbTable extends Zend_DB_Table_Abstract{
      protected $_name = "user"; // name of the table
      protected $_rowClass = "User"; // The name of your Zend_Db_Table_Row class
}

class User extends Zend_Db_Table_Row {

  public function set_name($_name){
    $this->name = $_name;
  }
  public function get_name(){
    return $this->name;
  }
  public function set_adresses($_addresses){
    $this->addresses = $_addresses;
  }
// and so on....
}
```

You can see more on `Zend_Db_Table_Row` [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.row.html)